# Los inputs dentro de un form (Flex item) se desbordan al ponerle un width 100%

Tags: css, formularios, input, flexbox, overflow

En un práctica de principiantes de DISPLAY FLEX sobre un formulario responsive con foto al lado tengo este código:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 150px 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pic img {
  opacity: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.form {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.pic {
  flex: 1;
}

.finput {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="number" placeholder="Tu edad aqui">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <textarea class="finput" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"> 
                   </textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://6.viki.io/image/fad24cd4a87c47078667cac63040006f/dummy.jpeg?s=900x600&e=t" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

El caso es que estoy siguiendo un video didáctico de YT y veo que a él no se le desbordan los inputs dentro de su form a pesar de tener el código prácticamente idéntico. Esto pasa en el momento que llamo a la clase `finput` y le pongo un `width` de 100%, a mí se me desbordan hasta ocupar visualmente un pedazo de la imagen de al lado, pero al chico de YT no.
Adjunto un par de capturas para que se vea la diferencia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería más una explicación del POR QUÉ pasa esto que una solución, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: a lo mejor su padre tiene un margen o madin negativo ...

Comment: He probado a literalmente calcar el código del chico de YT y me pasa el mismo problema al darle un width de 100%.
Igual tengo que mencionar que este chico en su documento tiene referenciado un archivo 'normalize' donde ajusta una pocas cosas como el tamaño de letra y margenes para el proyecto en general.  Igual es allí y lo miraré ahora. Igualmente gracias por el feedback rápido

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente ten en cuenta que el 100% el `margin` a menos que lo especifiques.

Es decir, suponiendo que el `padre` de ese `input` mida `500px` de largo. **100%** no es `500px`, pues le estás agregando `16px` de cada lado de `margin`. Es decir, que en total tu componente hijo mide **516**

Para eliminar lo del `margin` usa `box-sizing:border-box` que te dice que el 100% será tomado en cuenta a partir de el margen y bordes. Por lo que tu componente medirá esta vez, **500px**

Pero aún queda un último problema. Tu componente mide **500px** al igual que su padre pero sigue teniendo **8px de margen**, por lo que se saldra por **8px** ahora.

Para eso réstaselo del total del `width` con `width: calc(100% - 16px);` y tu componente ya no se verá desbordado

```css
.container{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 150px 50px;
        justify-content: center;

    }
    
        .pic img{
        opacity: 20%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
        .form{
        min-width: 400px;
        background-color: grey;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1;
    }
    
        .pic{
        flex: 1;
    }
        
        .finput{
        width: calc(100% - 16px);
        margin: 8px;
        padding: 8px;
        box-sizing:border-box;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <title>Document</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="pag3.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="container">
             <form class="form">
                 <div class="f">
                     <input class="finput" type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">
                 </div>
                 <div class="f">
                     <input class="finput" type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo">
                 </div>
                 <div class="f">
                     <input class="finput" type="number" placeholder="Tu edad aqui"> 
                </div>
                <div class="f">
                    <textarea class="finput" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"> 
                   </textarea>
                </div>
             </form>        
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="https://6.viki.io/image/fad24cd4a87c47078667cac63040006f/dummy.jpeg?s=900x600&e=t" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la didáctica respuesta y rápida a una pregunta de novato que es lo que soy, ahora puedo ponerle más empeño a esto ya que lo he entendido.
Eso sí, me sigue extrañando ver que lo hacía todo igual que el vídeo de YT pero a él le salía una cosa y a mi otra. Es en el 5:44:38 de este video https://youtu.be/OWKXEJN67FE
ya me quedo conforme con la respuesta y una vez más, gracias.

Comment: Desconozco el porqué, tendrías que copiar el codigo exacto para poderlo comparar.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que los `input` por defecto tienen `margin` y `padding` el cual se suma al ancho que ya es del `100%`.

#### Solución:

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Todos los `.f` sean `display: grid`
- A todos los `.finput` sacarles el `width`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 150px 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pic img {
  opacity: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.form {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.pic {
  flex: 1;
}

.f {
 display: grid;
}

.finput {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <input class="finput" type="number" placeholder="Tu edad aqui">
    </div>
    <div class="f">
      <textarea class="finput" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"> 
                   </textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://6.viki.io/image/fad24cd4a87c47078667cac63040006f/dummy.jpeg?s=900x600&e=t" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la didáctica respuesta y rápida a una pregunta de novato que es lo que soy, ahora puedo ponerle más empeño a esto ya que lo he entendido.
Eso sí, me sigue extrañando ver que lo hacía todo igual que el vídeo de YT pero a él le salía una cosa y a mi otra. Es en el 5:44:38 de este video https://youtu.be/OWKXEJN67FE
ya me quedo conforme con la respuesta y una vez más, gracias.

Comment: @MartinRR, `normalize` es un toolkit que sirve para sacar todos los estilos por defecto que tienen los elementos. [Más info](https://www.kodetop.com/diferencias-entre-reset-css-y-normalize-css/). Si la respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como acertada. Saludos!